# Populate angular form value using json data

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have json response `{"CustomerAccount":{"segment":"Enterprise","type":"Domestic"}}` this json get from another url.
what I did so far this json sent to second url built with angular and already print on console.

I tried to populate the json as a form value in angular page using `<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nama-ocr" name="{{ segment }}">`

Any one how to do it? what should I put on the component.ts file?

ALso tried populate.js by dannyvankooten from github but just working on non-angular html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright if I'm gathering everything correctly you already have the returned json object logging to console. I'm going to assume that you're logging the async return variable to the console. So I'm going to try to help you get that async object stored in a component object and to print the values to your html file.

In your typescript file, you need to export an interface that is structured the same as the data you expect to receive from your service. Do this right after your module imports:

```
...
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...

export interface CustomerAccountObject {
   CustomerAccount: {
      segment: string;
      type: string;
   }
}
```

Then later on in your ts file, declare your object:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
   public customerAccountObject: CustomerAccountObject; // We're defining an object and giving it the Type of the interface we just exported.
   ...
}
```

Now when you subscribe to your data via async, you set the returned json object to your customerAccountObject:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
   public customerAccountObject: CustomerAccountObject;
   ...

   constructor(){}

   this.yourHttpService.yourMethodOrEndPoint(yourParams).subscribe((result) => {
      this.customerAccountObject = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(this.customerAccountObject);
   });
```

Now on the html side, you can print your values like so, assuming you want the input VALUE to take the property value:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nama-ocr" name="some name" value="{{ customerAccountObject.CustomerAccount.segment }}">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @kenef, big thanks for explanation it said undefined (sorry I am new with angular). 

where to put this exactly? is it under construct?

`this.yourHttpService.yourMethodOrEndPoint(yourParams).subscribe((result) => {
   this.customerAccountObject = JSON.parse(result);
   console.log(this.customerAccountObject);
});`

Comment: @Bireon you place that code inside the instantiation of your class and after the constructor. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Bireon can you share your code in a jsfiddle or something of the sort? If I can take a look at your ts and html files I should be able to help you get your component working. I work in angular 7 and 8 every day for work and develop your requirements very often. Share some more code with me and I'll fix it, and then add a ton of comments explaining what I did and why I did it.

Comment: Hi @kenef, sure I will share it. What are you prefer a zip file or stackblitz?

Comment: See if you can't copy and paste your code into the html, css and js blocks in codepen. I have an environment set up here: https://codepen.io/Kenef/pen/mdbOqxE

This way we can both edit the code and chat.

Comment: Finally is working, thanks ya. Jist wrong put the order of script

Comment: Hi @kenef would you like check my other question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613610/set-a-default-value-for-angular-chain-dropdown?noredirect=1#comment101683499_57613610)

Comment: I took a look and provided an answer. Should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bind it using [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel), sample:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nama-ocr" name="segment" [(ngModel)]="myJSON['CustomerAccount']['segment']">
```

This will automatically update the value in input when your JSON is fetched or updated.

Working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqh7m6

Comment: Hi @Yash Krishan, Thanks in advance will try it.

Comment: Hii, I tested and worked with the static data, how to put the dynamic URI as json data? and so far I send the json data into the url actually

Comment: Check the link I've added, there I've updated the JSON dynamically.

Comment: Hi, I checked the link but still same as previous link

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how to put the dynamic URI as json data"?

Comment: I mean on this part that.`myJSON = {"CustomerAccount":{"segment":"Enterprise","type":"Domestic"}};` how to create dynamic value from get URL

Comment: So you want to fetch the JSON dynamically by a URL?

Comment: yes, so far i already pass the json to the console only. this is dynamic json actually

Comment: Thanks mate, I will upvote. On my question I put got the json from another url. Thanks for you help so far

Comment: hi @Yash Krishan, would you like to check my other question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613610/set-a-default-value-for-angular-chain-dropdown?noredirect=1#comment101683499_57613610)