# Set a default value for Angular chain dropdown

Tags: angular, dropdown

I had JSON country within ID, and what I want to is the defeulat value is set to selected, here my select code so far:

```
<select (change)="onNationalitySelected($event.target.value)" id="nationality" formControlName="nationality">
                <option value=""> {{'messages.dropdownselect' | translate}} </option>
                <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id" [selected]="country.id == '100'" >
                  {{ country.name }}
                </option>
              </select>
```

**.ts file**

```
  onNationalitySelected(nationalityId: number) {
    this.customer.coid = nationalityId;
    this.customer.nationality = this.countries.filter(
      c => (c.id == nationalityId)
    )[0].name;
```

I tried to set a default value for country is 100, but it's not working, the value still empty after saved to DB.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If the question is "how to pre-select one option", then this question has been asked a lot already and the answer is always the same: the single point of truth is the model. Not the view. So remove the [selected]="...", and just make sure that the value of the nationality form control, in your TypeScript code, is === to the ID of one of the countries displayed by the select.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, thanks for the comment, a lot of tried within the ngModel, etc.but no luck. What I want is to pre-populate the default value for option box without selected first. If you don't min can you please share a links? I tried to find it a whole day for this :(

Comment: You're using a reactive form, not a template-driven form. So ngModel is irrelevant. Again, the form control's value, in your TypeScript code, must be set to one of the coutries IDs. Post your TypeScript code. that's where it must happen.

Comment: Sorry @JBNizet, I don't get it, thanks by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ts

```
// Let's use FormGroup so we can add a control/default
countryForm: FormGroup;

// define our countries data
countries = [{
 id: '100',
 name: 'USA',
 code: 'USD'
},
{
 id: '200',
 name: 'Canada',
 code: 'CAD'
},
{
 id: '300',
 name: 'UK',
 code: 'GBP'
}];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
 // set country code 100 as default
 this.countryForm = this.fb.group({
  countryControl: [this.countries[0].id]
 });
}
```

html

```
// ngValue allows us to use an object for default value assignment
<option [ngValue]="country.id" *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.name}}</option>
```

I'm a little uncertain about `countryControl: [this.countries[0].id]`, if it doesn't work, try this instead: `countryControl: [this.countries[0]]`

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Yay!! Glad to help.